# Longest sequence with given color

Tags: algorithm, list, binary-search

Suppose we have a list of elements with values in Black and White. Is there an O(N) algorithm to find the longest sequence comprising of black elements?

I know that using binary search we can do at O(Nlog(N)). I am wondering if we can do better.

Comment: Re: "I know that using binary search we can do at O(Nlog(N))": What do you mean by this? Binary search is an O(log N) algorithm for finding a given value in a sorted array. It does not seem applicable to your problem at all. Are you sure you've described your problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was asking. Thanks for the response. My original problem was finding the longest increasing subsequence in a given list. The solution available online is of order O(Nlog(N)), but I think by a coloring argument we can reduce it to O(N).

Comment: Still not understanding why "look through them in order" is not the answer.  Just keep track of how many consecutive blacks you've currently found, how many is the most you've ever found so far, and the index that that longest-so-far started at.  When you get to the end, which you'll do in N steps, you're done.

Comment: @BobVesterman: I did not say this is not the answer. I am just trying to check if my understanding is correct for the longest increasing subsequence problem. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I think you must be misunderstanding the "longest increasing subsequence problem". That problem allows a *non-contiguous* subsequence; so for any given element, you can't immediately tell whether or not it represents an increase (because you don't know what the previous element was until you have the full solution). So there's no "coloring argument"; there's no reasonable way to map from the longest increasing subsequence problem to a problem where we can tell whether to include an element just by looking at it.

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep first value of array and index of it. And assign maxCount and maxIndex to keep where is longest sequence started.

```
Create oldValue and assign first value of array 
Create maxCount variable
Create maxIndex variable (it should be 0 because we use first value of array)

Move on array - start with 2nd element (because we used first already)
   if new value is equal old value
      go to next element and increase count
   else
      check if count > maxCount
         if so maxCount = count and maxIndex = i
         else count = 0 
   and oldValue = currentValue
```

Do that until reach the end of array. Also it's O(N). I don't write any code because I believe you should do it yourself. You can ask anything after you tried.

Answer (score 3):

I think Kadane's algorithm would give you the solution in the best time possible for this problem. Consider ListItems containing your 'Black' and 'Whites', so for an instance we keep track of how many 'Black' items we have counted so far continuously and if we encounter a 'White' than we reset our counter to zero AND if at any point, our count of element 'Black' or 'White' exceeds the global max count then we update the global count with the local count.

I've coded it in python, Comments and edits are most welcome. I'm new to StackOverflow (and coding).

Further, you can look it up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/) for better understanding.

```
ListItems = ['Black', 'White', 'Black', 'Black', 'White', 'White', 'White', 'White','Black','Black','Black','Black', 'White', 'White','Black', 'White', 'White','Black','Black', 'White', 'White']


maxi = 0
max_so_far = 0

for i in ListItems:
  if i =='Black':
    maxi += 1

  else:
    maxi = 0 

  if maxi > max_so_far:
    max_so_far = maxi

print(max_so_far)
```

Comment: Upvoted for hinting at Kadane's algorithm, which is the canonical approach.

Comment: @N.Wouda Thanks. After reading my solution again, even I thought it's not clear enough for someone to understand without any prior knowledge to Kadane's algorithm. Although one could/should try to look it up and find several links for the same for better understanding.

Answer (score -2):

I feel like I might be misunderstanding the question, but: Looking through them all in order, one by one?